# How to delete file with Turbo Assembly program?

Tags: file, assembly, tasm

I am trying to start simply by writing a program that deletes a file in the same folder as the program but when I run it i get "Illegal Path". Here's the code:

```
masm
model small
.data
filename    db  "my_file.txt"
point_fname dd  filename
.stack  256
.code
main:
     mov    ax,@data 
     mov    ds,ax
     lds    dx,point_fname 
     mov    ax,41h 
     int    21h
      jc    exit 
     nop 
exit:
     mov    ax,4c00h 
     int    21h
end  main
```

Shouldn't it be searching where the .ASM file of the program is or i should give the path name?

Also I am not sure how should i give the path to DX (as far as i am aware it should be set there) . Should i write it in the filename?

Comment: Wow, haven't seen this in ages! At first glance you want `mov ah,41h` not ax, and probably zero-terminate the filename (reference [here](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah41)). I can't remember if that's the correct way to load the data segment, sorry, but you probably do want `offset filename` not point_fname.

Comment: You're using TASM?   From Borland?

Comment: Well, Borland/Inprise/Enchilada/whatever-they-call-themselves-nowadays :-)

Comment: What is the intention to put directive masm (Microsoft assembler) in the direction? I deleted it and make the correction as suggested by @paxdiablo, it is works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things you need to look at.

---

As per [Ralf Brown's excellent interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm), deleting a file is done with int21/ah=41. By setting `ax` to `0041`, you're setting `ah` to zero which is the "terminate program" function. You need:

```
mov ah, 41h
```

---

Secondly, the filename is meant to be an ASCIZ, meaning it should be terminated by a zero byte:

```
filename    db  "my_file.txt", 0
```

---

Thirdly, you appear to have some unneeded indirection in there (a la `point_fname`). The `ds:dx` register pair should point directly at the file name and you should be able to do that without the extra data item.

You're stretching my memory here but I think you would ditch the `point_fname` and `lds` call and instead just load the offset of the filename directly into `dx` with something like:

```
mov  dx, offset filename
```

The indirection-with-lds method will probably *work,* but it seems an unnecessary complication.

---

You *may* also want to be careful that this sort of stuff still works in modern versions of Windows (it may, or it may not).

Microsoft is a big believer in backward compatibility but this stuff was introduced in MSDOS 2 and may not support such wondrous new thing as filenames beyond the 8.3 limit, or NTFS :-)

If you're running in DosBox or under a VM running Windows 98 or lesser, you should be fine, but I'd be at least a little circumspect about functionality beyond that.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. Despite from the little mistake i made on the ax/ah i was also using DosBox which seemed to cause a problem. Once i tried it on my old computer it worked perfectly ;]

Comment: @user3163847 The fact that you didn't put a 0 byte at the end of the filename is another genuine problem. If you didn't find that was a problem, perhaps you were (sometimes, but not on DosBox) lucky and the most significant byte of point_fname happened to be 0.